# Wrong argument type when writing quaternion orientation to pose message

Tags: python, moveit, ros-kinetic, quaternion, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit:**

I tried to just simply copy the quaternion values and hardcode them as an orientation coordinates. Results are the same, so maybe problem comes from another part of my grasp msg?
I dumped the message which I'm trying to use to pick my object: [link text](https://pastebin.com/xceknYxC)

---

Hi,
I'm trying to generate `moveit_msgs/Grasp Message` using Python API and I'm getting ROSSerializationException in place where calculated quaternion values are assigned into `geometry_msgs/Pose Message/orientation`.

Piece of code where I'm making Grasp message and trying to get quaternion from euler angles:

```
p = PickPlaceInterface("arm", "gripper", verbose=True)
g = Grasp()

g.id = "test"
gp = PoseStamped()
gp.header.frame_id = "base_link"
gp.pose.position.x = grasps[0].surface.x
gp.pose.position.y = grasps[0].surface.y
gp.pose.position.z = grasps[0].surface.z

quat = quaternion_from_euler(grasps[0].approach.x, grasps[0].approach.y, grasps[0].approach.z)

print ("Quat type: " + str(type(quat[0])))
print ("Pose orient type: " + str(type(gp.pose.orientation.x)))

gp.pose.orientation.x = float(quat[0]) 
gp.pose.orientation.y = float(quat[1])
gp.pose.orientation.z = float(quat[2])
gp.pose.orientation.w = float(quat[3])
g.grasp_pose = gp

g.pre_grasp_approach.direction.header.frame_id = "base_link"
g.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.x = 1.0 
g.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.y = 0.0 
g.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.z = 0.0 
g.pre_grasp_approach.min_distance = 0.001
g.pre_grasp_approach.desired_distance = 0.1 

g.pre_grasp_posture.header.frame_id = "base_link"
g.pre_grasp_posture.joint_names = ["gripper_axis"]
pos = JointTrajectoryPoint()
pos.positions.append(0.0)
g.pre_grasp_posture.points.append(pos)

g.grasp_posture.header.frame_id = "base_link"
g.grasp_posture.joint_names = ["gripper_axis"]
pos = JointTrajectoryPoint()
pos.positions.append(0.02)
pos.effort.append(0.0)
g.grasp_posture.points.append(pos)

g.allowed_touch_objects = []
g.max_contact_force = 0
g.grasp_quality = grasps[0].score

p.pickup("obj", [g, ], support_name="supp")
```

**grasps[0].approach** is a `geometry_msgs/Vector3` message.

**grasps** is a list of GraspConfig.msg which is defined here: [link text](https://github.com/atenpas/gpd/blob/master/msg/GraspConfig.msg)

I'm getting this exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pick_and_place.py", line 83, in <module>
    err = p.pickup("obj", [g, ], support_name="supp")   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_python/pick_place_interface.py", line 154, in pickup
    self._pick_action.send_goal(g)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actionlib/simple_action_client.py", line 92, in send_goal
    self.gh = self.action_client.send_goal(goal, self._handle_transition, self._handle_feedback)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actionlib/action_client.py", line 553, in send_goal
    return self.manager.init_goal(goal, transition_cb, feedback_cb)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actionlib/action_client.py", line 466, in init_goal
    self.send_goal_fn(action_goal)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 886, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e)) rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'x: 0.008194649141243238 y:
0.1413781390046223 z: 0.44856469150891914 w: 0.8824595101581431'
```

Looks simple, I'm just messing with types. But when I checked them with:

```
print ("Quat type: " + str(type(float(quat[0]))))
print ("Pose orient type: " + str(type(gp.pose.orientation.x)))
```

I'm getting:

```
Quat type: <type 'float'>
Pose orient type: <type 'float'>
```

And now I'm confused ... Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

I tried also numpy conversions and tricks mentioned here: [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/69754/quaternion-transformations-in-python/), but results are the same. I'm using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283885/wrong-argument-type-when-writing-quaternion-orientation-to-pose-message/) by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-02-28**:
What is type(quat[0])) ?

**Comment by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) on 2018-02-28**:
numpy.float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I figured out whats wrong. The problem is trivial, but because of the exception handling it was quite complicated to figure out whats wrong there.

Orientation values are completely OK, exception rises when **grasp_quality** value is serialized. I'm returning `std_msgs/Float32` as a **grasp_quality** value. Fix is very easy:

```
g.grasp_quality = grasps[0].score #WRONG! returns std_msgs/Float32
g.grasp_quality = grasps[0].score.data #returns float
```

Now interesting part. Why exception returns orientation values? Lets look how that data is serialized in **_PickupActionGoal.py** (autogenerated code :/):

```
_v14 = _v12.orientation
_x = _v14 
buff.write(_get_struct_4d().pack(_x.x, _x.y, _x.z, _x.w))
buff.write(_get_struct_d().pack(val1.grasp_quality) #boom, error

#and part where exception is handled
except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self)))))
```

Simply error printing uses **_x** to provide information where exception occured, but before writing **grasp_quality** value to buff **_x** is not updated, so it still contains orientation values, and those values are printed...

For me that looks like a bug, IMO **_x** should be updated before every **buff.write(...)**.

---

Originally posted by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) with karma: 56 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1